# Magento 1.9 Google site map generation 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sitemaps

I'm using magento 1.9.x version, recently i tried to generate google site map via

**Catalogue - > Google Site Map**

**But it gave 404 error**

Then i checked the code and identify the location of error here

```
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php
```

**Line No 165**

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sitemap_categories_generating_before', array(
            'collection' => $categories
        ));
```

When i comment out above code site map generates fine. In surface i can't see any side effect of comment that code,

Does anyone know will that effect for other functions of my site,

Comment: this code triggers event `sitemap_categories_generating_before` if any other module is using same event then its working may get affected.

Comment: i think it use by some other extension, but i cannot able to find it, which also break the site map generation process without any error or warning :(

Comment: you can run command `grep -ir "sitemap_categories_generating_before" app/ ` to find out module which is using this event.

Comment: Thanks mate if you can provide above as answer i can accept that, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that commented code triggers the event `sitemap_categories_generating_before` so possibly any third party module is using it which is causing `404` problem, you need to look into the code of that module.

You can find that module using command `grep -ir "sitemap_categories_generating_before" app/`.

please put comment if you want to get any assistance.

Comment: Thanks, nothing found on search results, so i think it's not effect by commenting that code.

Comment: but I strongly will not recommend you to do any changes in core files. you should copy this file to your `local` folder of magento.